# How Trust of website verified while using SSL

Tags: ssl, certificate

Assume I am trying to access hdfc bank website, be mistake I got similar website which is fake. say I want to access https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/ but by mistake I hit https://Netbanking.hdfcbank.com/Netbanking/ which is a fake website having similar or same look as genuine website.

So both will issue a certificate, uses may not identify its a fake or genuine and entered there details. Which will be used to stole your information.

My question is how your browser verifies the trust of the certificate issued by the server/provider.

As is it user job to check if it is a genuine website or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than capitalization, is there ANY difference between those two urls, and... offtopic. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL does not provide trust in a site. It only secures the transport but not the site itself. It is easy to buy a domain, get a certificate for it and setup a phishing page served with https. The browser will neither check if the site looks similar to some other site, nor if it serves malware or has severe security problems.

A bit more trust can be put into the EV certificates (green bar) because in this case the certificate agency will not only check if the potential owner of the certificates owns the site but also checks some business records and maybe will notice that the choosen domain name sounds too similar to same brand names. But since it is easy to create some shell company it is also possible to get EV certificates too and misuse these. It's just more expensive.